# language binding error with Fortran: why won't it link to MPI library?

Tags: linker, fortran, mpi, linker-errors, language-binding

I'm trying to create language bindings for a message passing interface but the compiler can't recognize my reference to the C functions...

I'm currently using gfortran as my compiler on a linux machine... I know the language bindings work, but whenever I try to link them to the mpi library, I get this error:

```
    /tmp/ccwukrNT.o: In function `MAIN__':
    hello_init.f90:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `mpi_init'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the commands to compile I am currently using are:

```
    gfortran -ffree-form foo.f90 ~/dir1/dir2/bar.f90 -o <outfile> -L  
    /home/.fakeroot/lib -I /home/.fakeroot/include/ -lexampi
```

(exampi is the standard I am currently working on)

As I said, when I use simple hello_world programs and compile all my files manually, this method works, but it fails when I try and link it to a library. Can anyone help me?

here is my current Fortran binding for MPI_Init:

```
    module mpi_f08

    interface MPI_Init
    subroutine MPI_Init(ierror) bind(C)

    integer, optional, intent(out) :: ierror

    end subroutine MPI_Init
    end interface MPI_Init

    end module mpi_f08
```

The C function I am using is trivial... it's merely interfacing with PMPI_Init()... In any event, the library linking is the main problem... Yes, I have externalized it from C++.

Here is the simple test program I wrote:

```
    program hello_init
    use mpi_f08, only : MPI_Init
    implicit none
    integer :: ierror
    ierror = 0
    call MPI_Init(ierror)
    stop
    end program hello_init
```

I am not too familiar with Fortran... this was given to me as a side project but it's quickly taking up my whole week *simultaneously laughs and cries*

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what is the symbol in library?  And, you failed to show us any Fortran code, so we have no idea if you're ISO C Binding.  BTW, what MPI implementation are you using?  The two open source MPI libraries that I am familiar with come with Fortran bindings.

Comment: lower case `mpi_init()` is **not** a `C` function (`MPI_Init()` is) if you write the FORTRAN bindings in C, then you have to mangle the name to match what your FORTRAN compiler expects (lower/upper case, {0,1,2} trailing underscores). Anyway, please upload a [MCVE].

Comment: @evets I am currently writing the bindings for a new open source MPI library : ExaMPI.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, and I don't know why the error returns it in that way... I have always made sure to follow the standard

Comment: how did you call your `C` function ? `void MPI_Init(Fint *ierror)` ? If so, and even if that looks fishy to me since the `C` binding is `int MPI_Init(int *argc, char ***argv)`, you can try to declare `subroutine MPI_Init(ierror) bind(C, name="MPI_Init")`. Feel free to look for inspirations in existing libraries such as Open MPI or MPICH.

Comment: The name of the language is Fortran.  It has been Fortran since 1990.  You did not answer my initial question.  What is the name of the symbol in the library?  Fortran is case insensitive.  You need to use the name of the symbol in the library, which may contain some mangling, as the binding label.

Comment: Fortran 66 was not released in 1990, and neither was Fortran 2008 ;-)

Comment: Neither FORTRAN 66 nor FORTRAN 77 contained ISO C BINDING facilities, so I think we can dispense with backwards compatibility.  Also, note that typing FORTRAN here is incorrect if one refers to Backus's original spelling, because the ORTRAN should be in a small-capital typeface.

Comment: That is the egg and the chicken problem (the OP is developing a new MPI library, `mpif90` might not be there yet)